# Facebook JS SDK - Posting a Photo "Inline"

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have success with the post using the below code example. But, the photo is not displayed "inline" on the post. Instead, it is shown as an attachment (paperclip) which, when clicked, opens the image.

```
FB.api('/page_id/photos', 'post', 
{ message: 'the message', url: 'http://www.mysite.com/myimage.jpg' }, 
function(response) { });
```

Does anyone know of a way, with the JS SDK, to post a photo inline?

Comment: I've recently noticed that posts I make to the /page_id/photos endpoint are also ending up in the "Recent Posts by Others" section of the fan page.  Does that help diagnose my issue?

Comment: Solved it. I was using a user access token. That seems to work when posting to the Page Wall.  But, when you want to post a **photo** to a page album or a page wall, you must use a page access token.

You can get a page access token by calling /{user_id}/accounts: